# Quelle expression est préférable dans le contexte:Il a fallu que ou j’ai dû?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Au sortir du cabinet d’un médecin spécialiste, j’ai été pris de malaise, de la sueur couvrait mon front, de la transpiration émanait de tout mon corps, ma conscience s’affaiblissait, il m’a fallu patienter sur une chaise, située dans le corridor faisant office de salle d’attente, avant de me rendre à la réception pour prendre mon prochain rendez-vous.

> Sur ordre de la réceptionniste, j’ai dû m’asseoir pour me remettre de mon malaise.

> Sur ordre de la réceptionniste, il a fallu que je m’asseye pour me remettre de mon malaise.

Auriez-vous d’autres façons de rendre cette idée sans recourir aux verbes « falloir » et « devoir »?

De plus, je me demande s’il est correct d’écrire « sur ordre », j’hésitais au début entre « sur ordre », « par ordre » et « à la demande de », qui est moins formel. J’hésite souvent devant le choix de la préposition à employer avec telle ou telle expression.

Je suis conscient qu’il existe plus d’une façon de s’exprimer, je veux seulement connaître la formule qui serait, eu égard au contexte, la plus adaptée.

Comment: « Ordre » ne convient probablement pas, mais il y a plusieurs façons de demander quelque chose, et il faudrait des précisions sur le ton de la demande, sur l'attitude de l'infirmière. ; il pourrait s'agir de « la demande pressante » de l'infirmière, par exemple.

Comment: « Demande pressante » a du sens, en effet. Dans ce cas, l’usage voudrait qu’on emploie la préposition « à », comme « à la demande pressante de… », si je ne m’abuse?

Comment: Pour ce qui est du verbe, « falloir » et « devoir » se valent-ils?

Comment: Ce n’est pas tant la justesse que l’élégance de l’expression qui m’intéresse dans ce cas-ci.

Comment: Ce qui est certain, en revanche, c’est que je serais heureux qu’on me présente une autre formule, si jamais il en est une.

Comment: La réceptionniste voyant que je faisais un malaise m'a aidé à m'asseoir et ce n'est qu'au bout d'un certain temps que j'ai pu reprendre mes esprits.

Comment: falloir faire quelque (avec le pronom impersonnel il) chose ou devoir faire quelque chose (conjugué avec les pronoms) dépend de ce qu'un locuteur **veut dire**. Et puis ici, je dirais: à la demande de la [personne].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En réalité, il me semble qu'il n'est même pas approprié de se servir de ces verbes, mais évidemment plus d'un lecteur pourra ne pas être d'accord avec ce point de vue, tant il tient à peu de chose. L'idée que la nécessité découle de l'injonction ne semble pas si satisfaisante ; apparemment, le malaise est sur le point de se terminer en une perte de connaissance, et le malade pas moins que l'infirmière en est conscient ; il doit donc ressentir que la nécessité vient de la gravité de son état ; de plus, l'expression « sur l'ordre de » ou « sur l'injonction de » n'appelle pas l'expression d'une nécessité mais celle d'un acte, idée qu'il m'est beaucoup plus difficile de justifier.

- sur l'injonction du policier il s'est résolu à …
- sur l'ordre de son supérieur il a dévoilé …

Les constructions suivantes correspondraient peut-être aux états d'esprit des protagonistes.

- Sur l'injonction expresse de la réceptionniste, j’ai consenti à m’asseoir pour me remettre de mon malaise.
- À la demande insistante de la réceptionniste, j'ai consenti à m'asseoir pour me remettre de mon malaise.
- En raison de la demande pressante de la réceptionniste que je prenne une chaise, j'ai résisté à/perdu mon impulsion de traverser cette crise sans m'attarder, et je me suis assis pour me remettre de mon malaise.
- Suite au conseil de la réceptionniste, je me suis résigné à m'asseoir pour me remettre de mon malaise.

Concernant ces phrases, si je ne parlerais en aucune façon de  formulation qui serait la plus appropriée de toutes celles possibles, je crois pouvoir dire qu'il ne devrait pas s'y trouver de gaucheries.

Comment: Tout à fait d’accord.

Comment: J’approuve entre autres qu’une injonction (ou qu’une demande) commande un acte, et non une nécessité, et évidemment j’étais conscient de ma faiblesse avant même qu’on me fasse la demande de m’asseoir, ce qui coïncide avec ce que vous avez déduit par vous-même.

Comment: @Jean-LouFrenette Personnellement, j'aimerais bien  lire une explication de cet état de chose, dont je suis convaincu, mais qui défie mes tentatives de réduction à un raisonnement assez logique.